# Either SnackBar or EditText hides behind Keyboard

Tags: android, kotlin

I've set up ConstraintSet transition using two separate layouts and the second one of them has more `EditTexts` so they hide behind the keyboard. Also, in the first one, when the submit button is clicked, `SnackBar` hides behind the keyboard.

What I've tried:

1. adjustresize: It works well to show the `SnackBar` above the keyboard but it doesn't work for edittexts.
2. adjustpan: It works well to show edittexts above the keyboard but it doesn't work for `SnackBar`.
3. adjustpan|adjustresize: It works as adjustresize.
4. FitSystemBounds: Apart from showing the statusbar white which I don't want, It doesn't help.
5. ScrollView: ScrollView doesn't work with ConstraintSet transition.

What I want? I want that `SnackBar` is shown above the keyboard, `EditText` above the keyboard and transparent statusbar. I've searched a lot before in these two days and only after that, I'm asking this question.